# All different functions

Tags: code-golf

For functions \$f, g: \{0,1\}^n \rightarrow \{0,1\} \$, we say \$f \sim g\$ if there's a permutation of \$1,2,3,...,n\$ called \$i_1,i_2,i_3,...,i_n\$ so that \$f(x_1,x_2,x_3,...,x_n) = g(x_{i_1},x_{i_2},x_{i_3},...,x_{i_n})\$. Therefore, all such functions are divided in several sets such that, for any two functions \$f, g\$ in a same set, \$f \sim g\$; for any two functions \$f, g\$ in different sets, \$f \not\sim g\$. (Equivalence relation) Given \$n\$, output these sets or one of each set.

Samples:

```
0 -> {0}, {1}
1 -> {0}, {1}, {a}, {!a}
2 -> {0}, {1}, {a, b}, {!a, !b}, {a & b}, {a | b}, {a & !b, b & !a}, {a | !b, b | !a}, {a ^ b}, {a ^ !b}, {!a & !b}, {!a | !b}
```

You can output the function as a possible expression(like what's done in the example, but should theoretically support \$n>26\$), a table marking outputs for all possible inputs (truth table), or a set containing inputs that make output \$1\$.

Shortest code win.

Comment: @JoKing Anything, so there are \$2^{2^n}\$ functions for given \$n\$.

Comment: @JoKing Also, all boolean functions can be represented in term of AND and OR.

Comment: @user202729 AND, OR, and NOT at the very least (not that this is a problem since you have used all three). Just AND and OR won't work.

Comment: Related: [A003180 - Number of equivalence classes of Boolean functions of n variables under action of symmetric group](https://oeis.org/A003180)

Answer (score 2):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), 62 bytes

```
f=:3 :'~.(2#~2^y)([:<@~.@/:~((i.@!A.i.)y)|:(y#2)$])@#:i.2^2^y'
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/r/P83WyljBSr1OT8NIuc4orlJTI9rKxqFOz0Hfqk5DI1PPQdFRL1NPs1KzxkqjUtlIUyVW00HZKlPPKA6oWP1/anJGvkKagtF/AA)

-3 bytes for anonymous function (removing `f=:`)

For each boolean function (truth table), generate its equivalence class, then remove duplicates.

Comment: Does it return 3D array truth table and can't output with `echo`?

Comment: @l4m2 I don't understand your question. J can print array of any dimensions.

Comment: or maybe I can't read it? I think `f(3)` outputs `{0,0},{0,a&b},{0,a&!b,0,b&!a,a&b,0},...`